# Can Cocos2d draw this graphic?

Tags: iphone, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, draw

I have a school project. Please see the following picture implemented under Android.

Someone in stackoverflow told me that Cocos2d is easy to use compared with opgl es and quartz 2d. But I still don't know where to start. I just got a book Cocos2d for Iphone 0.99 Beginner Guide. But seems not related to my project. My project is just draw lines and give different areas for different colors.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Cocos2D - it does not make sense to use a 2D OpenGL Framework if what you want actually is plain plotting without fancy animation.

Use Quartz / CoreGraphics.

Comment: right.. just make a uiview und write a custom draw function for it. cocos2d won't give you any advantage for this project and will only make it more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cocos2d draw it.

But need good mathematics for draw that circle and specify all the axises.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use Cocos2d to draw it, although it may be easier to simply draw the entire menu with photoshop/inkscape/whatever then use Cocos2d to render the image.

Comment: i like your suggestion :D  But the Professor will not allow me to do that.

Comment: @Don Li hahaha, I guessed that the professor might have something to do with it =P oh well, good luck!